# how to check a check box in tree-view when a tree-view node is selected / clicked in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

in c# windows application i have a tree view with different nodes associated with  Check Box for each node(this is for multiple Node Selection). how to change the Check Box property to checked when we click on respective node?

Comment: Please add code for what you have tried so far, so that others can help you better

Answer (score 0):

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode node = e.Node;
        node.Checked = true;
    }
```

Try this event ...